# Simplifying logic formula

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to learn some alghoritms of boolean logic and I encountered a problem wich i don't understand.

There is a expression and I don't understand how to simplify it.

$$(A \wedge \neg B) \vee(\neg A \wedge B) \implies(A \vee B) \wedge (\neg A \vee \neg B)$$

How am I supposed to simplify left part of expression to the right one?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Draw up a truth table and see that the two expressions always have the same value?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, i know, but this example is already done, when I got to the problem, I only got left part of expression and I must figure out right one. I know they are equal, I just don't know steps wich my teacher used.

Comment: @Brykyz The first thing you should do is figure out what "simpler" means. Why is the version on the right a "simplification" of the version on the left? A good way of understanding what "simplify" means (not just here but in many areas of mathematics, e.g. when in grade school you were asked to "simplify" rationals or "simplify" polynomials) is the notion of normal form. An abstract characterization of normal form is: $\mathsf{nf}(s)$ is equivalent to $s$ and if $s$ is equivalent to $t$ then $\mathsf{nf}(s)=\mathsf{nf}(t)$. A more concrete variation is with respect to a term rewriting system.

Comment: A normal form for a term rewriting system is simply a term that can't be rewritten. This is an instance of the abstract version by saying two terms are equivalent if they can be rewritten to the same normal form. Often term rewriting systems are created by orienting equivalences, e.g. we turn the "equality" $a(x+y)=ax+ay$ into the rewrite rule $a(x+y)\leadsto ax+ay$. At any rate, this is all setup to say that your RHS is in conjunctive normal form (CNF). So you can interpret "simplify" as reduce to CNF. The LHS happens to be in disjunctive normal form, hence my first question.

Comment: @DerekElkins My goal is prove by logical resolution that all rules together are wrong. I am using proof by dispute, hence I need to take my expression and make it into two expressions, since all rules are separated by logical AND. That's not exactly simplification, but I can't think out better word for that. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(A \wedge \neg B) \vee(\neg A \wedge B) &\implies [(A \wedge \neg B)\vee\neg A]\wedge[(A \wedge \neg B)\vee B]\\
&\implies [(A\vee\neg A)\wedge(\neg B\vee \neg A)]\wedge[(A\vee B)\wedge(\neg B\vee B)]\\
&\implies [T\wedge(\neg B\vee \neg A)]\wedge[(A\vee B)\wedge T]\\
&\implies (\neg B\vee \neg A)\wedge(A\vee B)\\
&\implies(A \vee B) \wedge (\neg A \vee \neg B)
\end{align*}

Comment: Just in case the answer is not obvious for some, the following properties were used: in the first two lines the associativity, then complementation, and last commutativity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws

Comment: Can you please explain first step a little more? I know there is associativity used, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: $X\vee(Y\wedge Z)\implies (X\vee Y)\wedge(X\vee Z)$. Take $A\wedge\neg B$ as $X$, $\neg A$ as $Y$ and $B$ as $Z$.